# Why can't Eclipse find my ModuleA from within my ModuleB

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, module

I'm using Eclipse 20190614-1200, with gradle 5.6.2.

I have several projects in my Eclipse workspace, each with their own module.  They were all imported from a gradle (5.6.2) project with a subproject for each module.  They're generally in a `foo.bar.<something>` package, where the something varies as one would expect.

```java
package foo.bar.baz;
// from module foo.bar.qux
import foo.bar.qux.Quux; // "the type foo.bar.qux.Quux is not accessible"

public class Corge implements Quux { // "the type foo.bar.qux.Quux is not accessible"
    // ...
}
```

Their `module-info.java` have the appropriate `requires` clauses.  This alone appears to be insufficient.

From the project's "Java Build Path" tab, I have tried placing the requisite project in both the module path and the class path (it won't let you do both at the same time).   Neither way works.

There's a lot of brokenness strewn throughout this workspace as a result of these projects not being set up properly.  It's at least possible that so long as I don't have any cyclic dependencies I could find a leaf module, fix it, and all my problems would come apart like a sweater when you pull on the wrong string...  No luck finding that string as yet.

What do I need to do to fix my workspace?

Comment: The gradle project has a bunch of script dedicated to building a list of packages to be passed as JVM `--add-opens` args.  But that's just runtime, it shouldn't affect javac at all.

Comment: Please [upgrade your outdated Eclipse](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Always_enable_major_upgrades) to avoid wasting time with already fixed issue. Is in the `foo.bar.baz` project in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_ tab _Projects_ the project `foo.bar.qux` added to the _Modulepath_ only? Or what do you mean by _"tried placing the requisite project in both the module path and the class path"_? Why you added it also to the classpath (that should give you an error)? What do you mean by `--add-opens` shouldn't affect javac at all? Eclipse has its own compiler.

Comment: I tried adding my projects to the classpath because adding them to the modulepath didn't work like I expected it to.

Comment: --add-opens is a JVM arg, and so is irrelevant, but I'd hoped that mentioning it might job someone's memory about whatever is actually going on here.

Comment: PS: I did upgrade my eclise install, didn't help.  I'll change the question to reflect this.

Comment: According to the title, you should have an error in `module-info.java` at `requires foo.bar.qux;`. According to the error message (`not accessible`), module `foo.bar.qux` does not export the package `foo.bar.qux`. In Java 9+ a package must not be contained in different modules (everything on the classpath is considered in the UNNAMED module). So adding the same JAR to the modulepath and to the classpath adds another issue.

Comment: I'm not doing both at once.  In fact, Eclipse specifically prevents this in the UI.  One related problem I had was that I wasn't adding a matching build.gradle `dependencies { implementation project(":foo.bar.baz") }`, but that shouldn't matter to eclipse, right?  I'm not running gradle tasks to build my project within eclipse, I'm just manually building from the project menu.

Comment: `... is not accessible` means, if there are no errors shown in your `foo.bar.baz`'s `module-info.java` (which contains the line `requires foo.bar.qux;`), the module `foo.bar.qux` is present, but does not export the package `foo.bar.qux`. Please show the errors shown in `module-info.java` of the module `foo.bar.baz`. If there are no errors, please show how the package `foo.bar.qux` is exported (does `foo.bar.qux`'s `module-info.java` contain the line `exports foo.bar.qux;`?).